# Is there a way to test whether an iPhone (5s) is failing to work on certain frequencies?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

A few weeks ago my iPhone (5s, T-Mobile) stopped roaming to AT&T "4G" towers.  It will still roam to older AT&T towers ("E", edge) and newer AT&T LTE towers.  I'm wondering whether there has been a hardware failure and my phone no longer works on the frequencies used by the AT&T 4G towers in question.

**Is there a way to test whether my iPhone is still functioning properly on the frequencies used by the towers it is not connecting to?**

Comment: I would assume the Apple Genius Bar would be your most likely source of help (even though I doubt they would be able to test specifically that). They would probably run diagnostics on the device which may, perhaps be useful. I think 15 minute appointments with them are free - that is, if you are within driving distance.

Answer (score 1):

The Genius bar *may* be able to help you by running diagnostics, but you can also try that yourself with [this project](https://github.com/anthonya1999/iOS-Diagnostics) that MITMs the diagnostics connection and dumps all data into an archive, you can try poking around in in and see if you can find anything relevant in it.

Another solution would require control of the mobile network but then you can definitely see why the phone isn't connecting to the desired networks (if the SIM allows it and the phone still doesn't connect then it's a phone failure).